# Export to CSV, it overwrite or append header and line each for every new row

Tags: python-3.x, export-to-csv, with-statement

It is a big DB with include several values, I have a script which read line by line and create a new line with data for exporting to CSV file.
new line is passed to a function that inside create CSV file and then try to write new line, the result is no exactly what I need.

I tried in several ways and check other question on forum, still found diferent outputs but not the expected.
I tried these:

1-
`with open(csv_file, 'wb') as csvfile:` or `with open(csv_file, 'ab') as csvfile:` 
result: `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

2-
`with open(csv_file, 'a') as csvfile:` result

```
IMSI,MSISDN,

VAL01,VAL02

IMSI,MSISDN,

VAL03,VAL04

IMSI,MSISDN,

VAL05,VAL06

IMSI,MSISDN,

VAL07,VAL08
```

3-
`with open(csv_file, 'w') as csvfile:`

```
IMSI,MSISDN,

VAL07,VAL08
```

result 3 is logical that file is overwriting and it does not append next line with subsequent value keeping the line before new line

if `with` statement separate `writer.writerow(val)` I break sense of it and return `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.`

the function new line pass is

```
def escribir(val):
    print(type(val))
    with open(csv_file, 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns)
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerow(val)
```

I checked type of pass value and it is correct for write on CSV

I expect to write in CSV file each different new line that pass to function, without repeat header, not break line between lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you calling `def escribir(val)` multiple times for the same output csv file?
if that's the case then remove `writer.writeheader()` from this function.
write a separate function/code snippet for writing the header information only once.

Comment: Thanks for tip, I create CSV berfore: 
```
with open(csv_file,'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns)
    writer.writeheader()
    pass
```
and then write new lines:
```
def escribir(val):
    with open(csv_file,'a', newline='') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns)
        writer.writerow(val)